HAXM cannot be installed in Android Studio
I've looked up a number of methods online, including trying to turn off hyper-v, enabling virtualisation, downloading the original files and installing them manually, but still can't get it to work.
I am getting the following error on manual installation:
enter image description here
However, my computer configuration is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz，my configuration meets the virtualisation requirements after checking the requirement.
I would like to know if the android emulator will work without installing HAXM as I am not able to launch even the sample application with the emulator. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to fix the HAXM installation issue or some other way to bypass HAXM and launch the emulator.

Solved. No need to use HAXM anymore, it's no longer updated. For 33 and above version, install AEHD as a replacement, this works for me.

Your CPU might meet the hardware requirements, but often the virtualisation options are disabled in the BIOS by default.
You probably need to enable VT-D in the BIOS, it's usually under CPU options or advanced options, it varies depending on the manufacturer.

Yes, I've tried turning on virtualisation in bios before, and after rebooting and observing on task manager that the CPU's virtualisation is enabled, but still doesn't work.

Chances are you have some ready-made HAXM installations. Uninstall and install the one required by Android Studio.
